# Monochromatic triangle in two closed set which cover the plane

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, ramsey-theory

I am reading Section on Euclidean Ramsey Theory in Ronald Graham's *Rudiments of Ramsey Theory*. Exercise 7.3 states that

> Show that if $E^2$ is covered by two **closed** sets of colors then every 3-point set occurs monochromatically.

The book provides little contextualization of the problem and is there any suggestion on a starting point to think about this?

Comment: What does it mean for a given 3-point set to "occur monochromatically"? Should the monochromatic triangle be a **translate** of the given triangle, or **congruent** to it, or **homothetic**, or just **similar**?

Comment: Perhaps it means  up to Euclidean motion. (combinations of translations and rotations)